# join array elements with specified element to be placed at the end

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I have an array

```
input = ["Hi","Bye","Hello","Jose","Juan",null,"How","","Disco"]
```

I want to always place the word "Bye" to the end of the joined string

I have tried with

```
input.filter(Boolean).join("@"))
```

expected output

```
"Hi@Hello@Jose@Juan@How@Disco@Bye"
```

I am looking for the best efficient way, or if there is a way to add a filter function along with Boolean filter

Comment: Why don't you just move `Bye` to the end of the array first?

Answer (score 0):

Use a filter function that compares with `Bye` after performing the boolean test.

Then append `@Bye` to the end of the result.

```js
input = ["Hi", "Bye", "Hello", "Jose", "Juan", null, "How", "", "Disco"];
console.log(input.filter(s => s && s != 'Bye').join("@") + '@Bye');
```

Comment: what if there are multiple `Bye` in input array?

Comment: This may not work as the word "Bye" may or maynot exist in the list every time!

Answer (score 0):

**1)** [Filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) `input` array that are not `empty`, `null` and along with filter you can count of `Bye`(There can be multiple `Bye`)

**2**) Create a new array that only contains `Bye` using [Array.from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) and append it after the filtered array.

**3)** Then, at last, you can [join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) array.

```js
const input = ["Hi", "Bye", "Hello", "Jose", "Juan", null, "How", "", "Disco"];

let length = 0;

const result = input
  .filter((s) => {
    if (s === "Bye") ++length;
    return s && s !== "Bye";
  })
  .concat(Array.from({ length }, () => "Bye"))
  .join("@");

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sort the `Bye`s to the end?

```js
const input = ['Hi', 'Bye', 'Hello', 'Jose', 'Juan', null, 'How', '', 'Disco'];

const output = input
  .filter(Boolean)
  .sort((a, b) => (a === 'Bye') - (b === 'Bye'))
  .join('@');

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score -1):

If it is a string then one way to get the result is to

```
const outputString=input.filter(Boolean).join("@"))+"@bye"
```

Comment: That won't remove `Bye` from the middle.